# How to fix api/auth/error issue of next-auth in production?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have set the following environment variables in Vercel:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://example.vercel.app (production) 
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000 (development)
```

Then authorized the following two redirect URLs in Google provider GCP console (https://console.cloud.google.com):

```
https://example.vercel.app/api/auth/callback/google
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google
```

**When I click my sign-in button, it redirects to this error URL: `https://example.vercel.app/api/auth/error`** and shows **"This page could not be found."** I also tried setting these values for the environment variables:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://example.vercel.app/api/auth 
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://example.vercel.app/api/auth/signin
```

But **the error persists**. In development (`https://localhost:3000`) I am able to sign-in successfully: when clicking the sign-in button, it correctly redirects me to this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F
```

and shows NextAuth default page:

[image: brower-img]

### My auth API `pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`:

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers'
    
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Providers.Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    jwt: {
      signingKey: {
        kty: 'oct',
        kid: `${process.env.kid}`,
        alg: 'HS512',
        k: `${process.env.k}`,
      },
      secret: `${process.env.SECRET}`,
    },
  },
  debug: true,
  theme: 'dark',
})
```

How to fix this issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @fuad9 what's the kid and k ? from process.env !

Answer (score 14):

I've always found somewhat misleading when the documentation of a library uses something like `https://example.com` without pointing out that it's literally an example. Luckily, this is easy to solve!

### 1. Correct domain on `NEXTAUTH_URL`

Since `https://example.vercel.app` is literally an example, instead of setting the `NEXTAUTH_URL` to it you should set it to *your own app domain*. You can get your app domain from the **Overview** page in Vercel, under **Domains**. In the following example the app domain would be `https://my-simple-app.vercel.app`:

[image: Screenshot of Overview page in Vercel showing the app domain]

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://my-simple-app.vercel.app (production)
```

### 2. Correct domain on GCP console

The same should be done in the GCP console, instead of putting `https://example.vercel.app/api/auth/callback/google`, you should put *your own app domain*, in the case of the example above, that would be `https://my-simple-app.vercel.app/api/auth/callback/google`:

[image: Screenshot of Google Cloud Platform console showing authorized URIs]

That should do it!

### Extra resources

In case you want further information I can recommend [this article](https://medium.com/geekculture/why-and-how-to-get-started-with-next-auth-61740558b45b). It starts from scratch and it helped me A LOT to clarify what I needed to get my authentication working with the Vercel deployment.

Comment: I have same issues but in development mode, when I use [...nextauth].js it gives me '/api/auth/error', but when I use such structure of file it works: "/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts"

Answer (score 5):

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import RedditProvider from "next-auth/providers/reddit"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
    
export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    RedditProvider({
      clientId: process.env.REDDIT_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
    })
  ],
  secret: 'IamVeryHandsome' 
})
```

its worked for me puth the **secret: 'anystring'**. thanks יאיר אלמליח
i use
"next": "12.1.6",
"next-auth": "^4.5.0",

**appreciated**

Answer (score 3):

Add an environment variable called NEXTAUTH_SECRET with a random value, for example:

NEXTAUTH_SECRET=atr5-gt65-9jet

Although Next Auth works on localhost just fine, it needs that Secret to work in production.

[NEXTAUTH_SECRET][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64eVM.png

Answer (score 1):

Define a secret like this:

1. Add `SECRET="MY_STRONG_SECRET"` to your `.env` file.
2. Replace `MY_STRONG_SECRET` with a strong secret generated by a tool
   like https://generate-secret.vercel.app/32
3. Add secret: `process.env.SECRET`, at the same level as the providers
   array to `pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`.

Answer (score 1):

Geyler Pedroso Sanchez answer work very well for me i follow is intruction which is

Add an environment variable called NEXTAUTH_SECRET with a random value, for example:

```
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=atr5-gt65-9jet
```

and it works very well for me

Answer (score 0):

If you still get this error after assigning NEXTAUTH_URL in your environment variables , try to add a secret key with any string value to your [...nextauth].js file after providers array...

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  // ******** !!!! ADD BELOW LINE !!!! **********
  secret: "PLACE-HERE-ANY-STRING",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem it was solved after i do some changes in mongo database by changing ip address to 0.0.0.0/0 and deleting the node_modules folder and add it using yarn install command in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue:
check your .env file and if your
is NEXT_PUBLIC_NEXTAUTH_URL then please remove NEXT_AUTH Prefix and make your variable as NEXTAUTH_URL
I hope it will fix the issue because this way I fixed my issue. Thanks