# Next.js Auth Working Locally but Fails on Deployment - Server Error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, next-auth

**Details:**

- I'm using Next.js for my project.
- The authentication mechanism is implemented using NEXT Auth.
- Locally, when I run my application using `npm run dev` and access it at `localhost:3000`, the authentication works as expected.
- However, when I deploy my application, I encounter the mentioned server error.
- I've checked the server logs, but there's no additional information provided.

**Deployment Environment:**

- I tried to deploy on both vercel and netify but encountered the same problem on both of them
  (https://note-me-omega.vercel.app/)

**Additional Information:**

- I've followed the documentation and guides for setting up NEXT Auth.
- I've ensured that the environment variables are correctly configured.
- The deployment process was completed without any errors.

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone encountered a similar issue with NEXT Auth during deployment?
2. Are there specific configurations or steps I might be missing in the deployment environment?
3. How can I troubleshoot and get more detailed information about the server error during deployment?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

/src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/option.js

```
import GitHubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const options = {
  site : 'https://note-me-omega.vercel.app',
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
      profile(profile) {
        console.log("Github Profile", profile);
        let userRole = "github user";
        if (profile?.email === 'test@gmail.com') {
          userRole = "admin";
        }
        return { ...profile, role: userRole };
      },
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),

    CredentialsProvider({
      user : "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "mail",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "enter email",
        },
        password: {
          label: "password",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "enter password",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const user = { email: "user@mail.com", password: "123123" };
        if (
          credentials.email === user.email &&
          credentials.password === user.password
        ) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
   
  ],
  database: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  theme: {
    colorScheme: "light", // "auto" | "dark" | "light"
    brandColor: "#5FA5F9", // Hex color code

export default options;
```

middleware.js

```
export {default} from "next-auth/middleware"
```

page.js

```
"use client"
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import Notes from "../components/Notes";
import axios from 'axios';
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

import { useEffect } from 'react';

const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/customers');
    const data = response.data;
    console.log('Data from API:', data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  }
};

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const togglePublicNotes = () => {
    setShowPublicNotes(!showPublicNotes);
  };

  return (
    <SessionProvider className="">
      <Navbar onTogglePublicNotes={togglePublicNotes} />
      <Notes />
   </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

Error iam facing on deployed site
[Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL4zw.png)

Thanks

Comment: your error is similar to this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029244/how-to-fix-api-auth-error-issue-of-next-auth-in-production.

Comment: Have you added `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` environment variable to Vercel?

Comment: Yeah i have added a 64-digit string in the'NEXTAUTH_SECRET'